# Using the projection of a layer variable to project another in Model Builder in ArcGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

So in model builder I would like to have one input feature class projected to match the projection of another layer (a raster layer) that is a variable in the model. Can anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: Is the projection a custom projection? I.e., not one you can choose from a list or dropdown?

Comment: It is a custom projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **Calculate Value** tool with a bit of **arcpy** to retrieve the coordinate system of your raster then pass it to the **Project** tool as an output coordinate system.

1. In model builder, connect your raster dataset as precondition to the Calculate Value tool
2. Within the Calculate Value tool's **code block**, add this

   ```
   def rasterPrj(raster):
     return arcpy.Describe(raster).spatialReference
   ```
3. Set the Data Type as **Spatial Reference**
4. Type this in the expression **rasterPrj("%inRas%")**